# table view can not display after navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I met an issue which is the table view in second page can not display after navigation from the first page.

The first page redirect code is:

```
- (IBAction)searchProducts:(id)sender {
    ProductsViewController *proViewController = [[ProductsViewController alloc] init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:proViewController animated:YES];
}
```

In productsViewController:

```
#import "ProductsViewController.h"
#import "OriginViewController.h"
#import "Product.h"

@interface ProductsViewController ()

@end

@implementation ProductsViewController
NSArray *products;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Product *product1 = [Product new];
    product1.name = @"马克杯";
    product1.detail = @"¥57.00 - 64.00";
    product1.imageFile = @"cup1.jpg";

    products = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:product1, nil];

    UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 0, 0);
    self.tableView.contentInset = inset;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return products.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"INIT CELL.");

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Product *product = [products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImageView *productImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    productImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:product.imageFile];

    UILabel *productNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    productNameLabel.text = product.name;

    UILabel *productDetailLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    productDetailLabel.text = product.detail;

    return cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Two points can be sure:

- CellForRowAtIndexPath method have been called.
- ViewDidLoad have been called.

Did someone have a hint for me ? Thanks.

Comment: if I added button in first page and 'modal' to product controller, it works fine.

Comment: Check self.view.frame after viewDidLoad have been called.

Comment: Check table view frame.

Comment: Where are you setting these tags?

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala actually, you are right, I found I do not set these tags, and also I create a new view, and do not use viewWithTag to get each control in cell, it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to set tags if you are using `UITableViewCell` and not using a custom one.

You can just do

```
[cell.imageView  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:product.imageFile]];
[cell.textLabel setText:product.name];
[cell.detailLabel setText:product.detail];
```

If you are using custom cell, then you can set tag to retrieve the views or just set property or you can take any approach as you want. But if you are using Apple's default `UITableViewCell` then it by default provides you certain type of cells which contains `label`s and `imageView`s.

Look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

After you fill the array, try to call

> [myTableView reloadData];

It calls the delegate methods of UITableView and sets the data to the cells from your array.